# add the new value from input field to a div while keeping the old input in previous div

Tags: javascript, input, createelement

I want to be able to extract the value from the input field and add it to a created div and each time a new div is created it will take a new value while leaving the old values in place. Right now the new value overwrites all of the other values.

If you see my example; the plus sign adds a book to the shelf, then submitting the input field should add a title. However, after adding subsequent books the previous titles are overwritten.

I appreciate any help.

```js
const shelf         = document.getElementById('shelf');
const addBookBtn    = document.getElementById('add-book');
const submitFormBtn = document.getElementById('submitform');

function addBook() {

  const book = document.createElement('div');
  book.classList.add('book');
  shelf.appendChild(book);

}

addBookBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addBook();
});

submitFormBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var title = document.getElementById('booktitle').value;
  var book = document.querySelectorAll('.book')
  for (let b = 0; b < book.length; b++) {
    book[b].textContent = title;
  }

});
```

```css
#shelf {
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25px, 40px));
  align-items: end;
}

.book {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bookshelf">

  <div id="shelf"></div>

</div>

<button id="add-book">+</button>

<form>

  <label for="booktitle">Book Title</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="booktitle" name="booktitle"><br>

  <input type="submit" id="submitform" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Why do you have two buttons, that's confusing. Use one button that adds a book and fills in its title.

Comment: Its because the form will only show if the add book button is clicked. I just simplified the code for the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do this test

```
if ( book.textContent == '' )  // set value if empty
   book.textContent = myForm.booktitle.value;
```

which is the  same as [Logical OR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)  (||=)

```
book.textContent ||= myForm.booktitle.value;
```

```js
const
  shelf      = document.getElementById('shelf')
, addBookBtn = document.getElementById('add-book')
, myForm     = document.getElementById('my-form')
, BooksElms  = []
  ;
addBookBtn.addEventListener('click', () => 
  {
  let book = document.createElement('div');
  book.classList.add('book');
  shelf.appendChild(book);
  BooksElms.push(book);
  });
myForm.addEventListener('submit', e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault();
  BooksElms.forEach( book =>
    {
    book.textContent ||= myForm.booktitle.value; 
    });
  });
```

```css
#shelf {
  height                : 150px;
  border-bottom         : 5px solid #000;
  display               : grid;
  grid-template-columns : repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25px, 40px));
  align-items           : end;
  }
.book {
  border           : 1px solid #000;
  height           : 100px;
  width            : 25px;
  display          : inline-block;
  padding-top      : 5px;
  writing-mode     : vertical-rl;
  }
```

```html
<div id="bookshelf">
  <div id="shelf"></div>
</div>

<button id="add-book">+</button>

<form  id="my-form">
  <label>Book Title</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="booktitle">
  <br>

  <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this solution and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the title to the divs in a loop. Use a global variable to hold the index of the book to add the title to. Every time you submit, you add the title to that book and increment the index.

```js
const shelf         = document.getElementById('shelf');
const addBookBtn    = document.getElementById('add-book');
const submitFormBtn = document.getElementById('submitform');
let book_index = 0;

function addBook() {

  const book = document.createElement('div');
  book.classList.add('book');
  shelf.appendChild(book);

}

addBookBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addBook();
});

submitFormBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var title = document.getElementById('booktitle').value;
  var book = document.querySelectorAll('.book')
  if (book_index < book.length) {
    book[book_index++].textContent = title;
  } else {
    alert("You need to add another book first");
  }
});
```

```css
#shelf {
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25px, 40px));
  align-items: end;
}

.book {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bookshelf">

  <div id="shelf"></div>

</div>

<button id="add-book">+</button>

<form>

  <label for="booktitle">Book Title</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="booktitle" name="booktitle"><br>

  <input type="submit" id="submitform" value="Submit">

</form>
```